# Reusing PROCEDURE/ FUNCTION whichever to do the same thing using different values

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have many procedures that do the same thing:
they refresh materialized view and check if the count is not 0, then push that data into production tables. this is the skeleton of what each one does, the only thing that changes is the name of the materialized view. I thought about creating one function that will take in the name of the MV and process it, but it is not working :(

```
create or replace 
function  REFRESH_MV (mv_to_refresh IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
AUTHID CURRENT_USER 
AS

COUNTS INT;
begin
     DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(mv_to_refresh,'C');

     COMMIT;
     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO COUNTS FROM 'SEMANTIC.' || mv_to_refresh;

     IF COUNTS = 0 THEN  
        RETURN 'SEMANTIC.' || mv_to_refresh || ' is empty';
     ELSE
        'SEMANTIC_READ_ONLY.' || RELOAD_TABLE(mv_to_refresh);        
        RETURN  'SEMANTIC_READ_ONLY.' || mv_to_refresh || ' has been refreshed today';
     END IF;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use dynamic SQL for this purpose:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REFRESH_MV (mv_to_refresh IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    AUTHID CURRENT_USER 
AS
  COUNTS INT;
  VSQL VARCHAR2(100);
begin
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('SEMANTIC.' || mv_to_refresh, 'C');
    COMMIT;

    VSQL := 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM SEMANTIC.' || mv_to_refresh;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VSQL INTO COUNTS;

    IF COUNTS = 0 THEN  
        RETURN 'SEMANTIC.' || mv_to_refresh || ' is empty';
    ELSE
        SEMANTIC_READ_ONLY.RELOAD_TABLE(mv_to_refresh);  
        RETURN  'SEMANTIC_READ_ONLY.' || mv_to_refresh
        || ' has been refreshed today';
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RETURN 'Error has occured: ' || SQLERRM;
END;
```

Please make sure you pass view name without schema prefix as input parameter.

You should also note that scince it function it should return value or raise exception. But in you example function will return nothing in case of exception.

I didn't quite get the semantics of RELOAD_TABLE() procedure. In example given it is supposed to be a some procedure in SEMANTIC_READ_ONLY schema. In case you really need the appropriate function to be evaluated dynamically, you again can use dynamic SQL to construct the valid string contaning the code and call it:

```
vsql := 'begin SCHEMA_NAME.' || GET_PROCEDURE_FOR(mv_to_refresh) || '; end;';
execute immediate vsql;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or `DBMS_SQL` to do that; the first one should be easier to use in your case.

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'SEMANTIC.' || mv_to_refresh  INTO COUNTS;
```

should do the trick.